# Java generics - How to add non generic to a generic list

Tags: java, generics

I'm attempting to create a method that will add elements from a defined list, into a generic list.

Here is the code:

```
private List<IEntity> entities = new ArrayList<IEntity>();

public <T extends IEntity> List<T> values(Class<T> type) {
    List<T> types = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (IEntity v : entities) {
        types.add(v); //Error
    }

    return types;
}
```

The sytax error occurs on `types.add(v);` with the error message `(T) in List cannot be applied to (com.test.entities.IEntity)`.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do efficiently without having to cast?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler is giving you a type error because your program is not safe.

You have a `List<T>`.  You don't know what `T` is, just that it extends `IEntity`.  (Let's use Number as an example instead of `IEntity`, to make it more clear.)  So you have a List of some kind of Number, maybe it's a `List<Integer>`, or maybe a `List<Float>`, you don't know.  And you're trying to add a Number to it.  But you have no reason to believe that this list can hold Number!  A `List<Integer>` cannot hold an arbitrary Number, because you can't put Long or Float or Short into a `List<Integer>` -- Java generics are invariant.

So, basically your program is broken and the compiler is telling you so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert a `IEntity` to a list that holds subclasses of `IEntity` - `T extends IEntity`. You would need a list that holds super classes of `IEntity` to put an `IEntity` in it - `T super IEntity`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't provide more information about the concrete structure of what you're going to do, it's difficult to offer a better solution.

```
interface Entity {} // In Java, unlike in .NET environment, interface names do not begin with "I". You write Entity or EntityInterface, sometimes also EntityInt

class EntityImpl {
    private final List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    // List of T is undefined
    public <T extends Entity> List<T> getValues(Class<T> type) { // in Java it's important to write "get" for a getter-method before the property-name, if it's not a boolean-getter.
        List<T> types = new ArrayList<>();
        types.addAll((Collection<? extends T>) entities);
        return types;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a generic class you could do something like this.

```
private class MyClass<T extends IEntity> {
    private List<T> entities;

    ...

    public List<T> values() {
        List<T> types = new ArrayList<>();

        for (T v : entities) {
            types.add(v); // All Good
        }
        return types;
    }
} 

interface IEntity { ... }

interface ISubEntity extends {...}
```

Then when you know you are using ISubEntity, you can instantiate as follows;

```
MyClass<ISubEntity> myClass = new MyClass<>();
```

Subsequent calls to values would then return a List typed for you.

Here is the formal [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) online about generics.